# RSS feed URL for post comment shows HTML source code of page

Tags: permalinks, comments, rss, feed

I am facing a weird issue on my site. When I type RSS feed links, global feed and comments work correctly. But, when I go on a specific post, and enter (mysiteurl.com/postname/feed), It just gives me the HTML source of that page, instead of comments feed.

I have latest WordPress 5.8. My permalink structure is working correctly. Just the post comment feed is not working.

How can it be solved ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the culprit. The issue is due to a conflict with my page builder plugin - Live Composer.

I have reported a bug to them.